# Pandas excel insert data/url in A1 cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas, cell

I want to have an url in single cell (A1).
My `DataFrame` is from python dict and it's without this url. But I have it under variable `url`. I've tried `df.iat` and it did not work.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=collection)
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname)
df.iat[0, 0] = url
```

On picture, I've markup where the url should be.

Any ideas ?

[image: where to put data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of searching I found that this works:

```
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
...
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheetname]
worksheet.write('A1', url)
```

Comment: See also [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you just want to fill in one single cell in Excel, don't you?

```
# df_cell is a df with your url, and nothing more
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = load_workbook(filename)
startrow = 1
df_cell.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)
```